# Problema en el orden de validacion de patrones en las regex de opcion multiple

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, validación

```py
import re

x = input()

#OPCION 1 EN DONDE ESTA EL FALLO
regex_patron_m1 = r"\s*((?:\w+\s*)+) \s*\¿?(?:tu necesitas|tu necesitaria |tu necesitarias |necesitas |necesita )\s*((?:\w+\s*)+)\s*\??"

#OPCION 2 DONDE NO ESTA EL FALLO, PERO SE HAN QUITADO LAS ULTIMAS OPCIONES
regex_patron_m1 = r"\s*((?:\w+\s*)+) \s*\¿?(?:tu necesitas|tu necesitaria |tu necesitarias )\s*((?:\w+\s*)+)\s*\??"


m1 = re.search(regex_patron_m1, x, re.IGNORECASE) #Con esto valido la regex haber si entra o no en el bloque de code

if m1:
    word, association = m1.groups()

    word = word.strip()
    association = association.strip()

    print(word)
    print(association)
```

Con la regex 1 donde no quite `|necesitas |necesita` , lo que sucese es que aunque se supone que las opciones se van validando de izquierda a derecha y si hay coincidencia termina ahi, pero en este caso sucede que se valida hasta el final o quizas empieze de derecha a izquierda, pero de algun modo se valida `necesita` y no `tu necesitas`, por lo que al extraer las palabras queda el `'tu'` que deberia haber extraido.

Si ingreso: `para programar tu necesitas una pc`

con la regex 1 del codigo queda:

```
para programar
una pc
```

Lo cual es correcto.

Pero si ingreso lo mismo pero en la regex 2 del codigo queda:

```
para programar tu
una pc
```

Lo cual no seria correcto.

¿Que deberia hacer para poder usar la regex completa(osea la regex 1), y que si se da coincidencia de izquierda a derecha la regex deje de intentar?

```py
regex_patron_m1 = r"\s*((?:\w+\s*)+) \s*\¿?(?:tu necesitas|tu necesitaria |tu necesitarias |necesitas |necesita )\s*((?:\w+\s*)+)\s*\??"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Causa del problema

La raíz del problema está en esta parte de la expresión regular:

```
(tu necesitas|tu necesitaria |tu necesitarias |necesitas |necesita )
```

En ella la palabre "necesitas" aparece dos veces; con y sin "tu". Antes de ésta tienes otra expresión que reconoce cualquier texto arbitrario que venga antes.

Lo importante es que las expresiones regulares son **greedy** (codiciosas); quieren abarcar tanto como sea posible. Eso significa que es mejor elegir la alternativa "necesitas" en lugar de "tu necesitas", pues eso hace más larga la captura del texto previo.

Esto no cambia incluso si aplicas la opción **no-greedy** en el patrón; el problema raíz es que la misma palabra aparece dos veces.

#### Solución

No hay que romperse la cabeza con expresiones regulares. Si llegas al punto en que se pone díficil, puedes usar combinar distintas técnicas.

En este caso, reducire la expresión a lo esencial y obtendre el resto a partir de rebanadas. Esta es la expresión:

```
(tu necesitas |tu necesitaria |tu necesitarias |necesitas |necesita )
```

y este el código completo:

```
import re

patron = re.compile("(tu necesitas |tu necesitaria |tu necesitarias |necesitas |necesita )")


tests = [
    "para programar tu necesitas una pc",
    "vi vas a compras, necesitas llevar dinero",
    "para ir necesitarias permiso",
    "tu necesitas ponerte al día",
    "una buenas vacaciones es lo que tu necesitas ",
    "más energía en tu vida tu necesitarias ",
    ]

for test in tests:
    m = patron.search(test)
    if m:
        start = m.start(1)
        end = m.end(1)
        pre = test[:start]
        mat = test[start:end]
        post = test[end:]
        print(f"Frase: {test}")
        print(f"  pre: {pre}")
        print(f"  match: {mat}")
        print(f"  post: {post}")
```

La función `search` retorna un *match object* con información. En particular, las funciones `start(grupo)` y `end(grupo)` me dan los indices en el texto original del patrón encontrado. El grupo 0 contiene el texto completo, y el grupo 1 contiene el primer grupo de captura.

**Resultado**

```
Frase: para programar tu necesitas una pc
  pre: para programar 
  match: tu necesitas 
  post: una pc
Frase: vi vas a compras, necesitas llevar dinero
  pre: vi vas a compras, 
  match: necesitas 
  post: llevar dinero
Frase: tu necesitas ponerte al día
  pre: 
  match: tu necesitas 
  post: ponerte al día
Frase: una buenas vacaciones es lo que tu necesitas 
  pre: una buenas vacaciones es lo que 
  match: tu necesitas 
  post: 
Frase: más energía en tu vida tu necesitarias 
  pre: más energía en tu vida 
  match: tu necesitarias 
  post: 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! estube probando hace rato con las regex, y estaba encontrandome con ese problema del orden de validacion.

Answer (score 1):

### El problema

Hay un problema en la interpretación que le das a la prueba que has hecho, `regex` siempre se ejecuta revisando patrones de izquierda a derecha, esta certeza es la que permite que el "código" sea reproducible y sea confiable. Se podría hacer que para condiciones `or` se ejecutase al revés pero sería una mala práctica y tendrían que haber motivos muy fuertes para que quien lo programó lo deje así.

**Regex siempre se ejecuta de izquierda a derecha**

Como afirma @CandidMoe el problema es que el patrón previo está siendo codicioso (**greedy**) tomando `tu` sin dejar que el siguiente patrón lo considere:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo, nótese que si pones más adelante el mismo texto, el primer patrón capta `para programar tu necesitas una pc tu`, no se le está dejando lugar a `tu necesitas` por que el `tu` ya lo tomó el patrón previo.

### Solución

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El comportamiento **greedy**, de tomar la coincidencia más larga posible está por defecto en los cuantificadores (`*` y `+`) puedes desactivarla usando (`*?` y `+?`) respectivamente.

- se agregó `?` después de la `\s*` ya que esa sintaxis agrega palabras `word`  con espacios, `tu`  también es considerado. Si obligas que la última coincidencia tenga un espacio dentro del "bucle" y también afuera será un problema, porque tratará buscar dos o más espacios primero (**greedy**)
- El regex se puede limpiar más, aconsejo utilizar solo`\s?` sin cuantificador ya que las palabras solo tienen un espacio de separación. como ya está incluido no lo vuelvas a incluir afuera `(\w*\s)\s`

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme con esa duda!